# Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraints

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to go through the `YesNo` example from `Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!` book.

Here is my source code:

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()

main = putStrLn ( show (yesno 12) )

class YesNo a where
    yesno :: a -> Bool


instance YesNo Bool where
    yesno b = b

instance YesNo [a] where
    yesno [] = False
    yesno _ = True


instance YesNo Int where
    yesno 0 = False
    yesno _ = True
```

When I execute this code following exception occurs:

```
Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraints:
  (YesNo a0) arising from a use of `yesno'
             at /Users/mkhadikov/Projects/personal/haskell/hello-world/yesno.hs:5:25-29
  (Num a0) arising from the literal `12'
           at /Users/mkhadikov/Projects/personal/haskell/hello-world/yesno.hs:5:31-32
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the first argument of `show', namely `(yesno 12)'
In the first argument of `putStrLn', namely `(show (yesno 12))'
In the expression: putStrLn (show (yesno 12))
```

Can you please explain what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The problem is that it doesn't know what type 12 is! It can be *any* type with a Num instance:

```
GHCi> :t 12
12 :: Num a => a
```

You need to specify the type you want directly: try `putStrLn (show (yesno (12 :: Int)))`.

Why can't GHC pick Int, since no other choice would work, you ask? Good question. The answer is that with Haskell's typeclass system, adding an instance can never invalidate existing correct programs or change their behaviour. (This is referred to as the *open world assumption*.) If it did pick Int, then what would happen if you added `instance YesNo Integer`? The choice would become ambiguous, and your program would break!

So when you want to use a typeclass like this with a polymorphic value, you have to specify what type you mean more precisely. This shouldn't come up much in practice, since there'll usually be some surrounding context to force the type to be what you want; it's mainly numeric literals that are affected by this.

Comment: thanks for this beautifully written comment: it follows the way a newbie thinks.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that `12` actually has type `Num a => a` and not `Int` as you expect. If you add an explicit type anotation such as `12 :: Int`, it should compile.

Comment: Is it possible to create your own kind of data constructors that work like `12` in haskell? It seems that whenever you create a data constructor, it constructs a value of a single type. But when you write `12`, as you can see it constructs not a value of a single type, but a value of any type where the type is constrained by Num. Thus `Num a => a`. Am I interpreting this correctly? Is this kind of like constructing a value which has a existential/union?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I'm a bit fuzzy on the details but basically the typeclass `Num` contains a function `fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a`. A numeric literal works as if `fromInteger` was called on it.

Comment: Ah, so the `a` does kind of become an existential/union. Very interesting.

Comment: What is the implementation though? That's the type signature, what's the actual function implementation? Or is it kind of like a GADT kind of thing? (where the implementation is just inferred) Otherwise I would like to create my own fromSomething to create a typeclass constrained value rather than a typed value.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Not really. The quantor is `forall`; the fully qualified type is `fromInteger :: forall a. Num a => Integer -> a`. Since `fromInteger` is a type class member, ghci chooses the implementation of `fromInteger` appropriate for the type you want to get.

Comment: The forall makes it an existential doesn't it?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai No. `exists a.` would make it existential.

Comment: Ok so how would you write your own version of `fromSomething` for your own type class?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai That depends on what your type looks like. You get an `Integer` and you have to convert it to a variable of your type. It seems like you got confused over the terminology here. I think you mean *your own type* and not *your own type class.*

Comment: Ok do you have a reference to the actual implementation of the `fromInteger` function? Not just the type signature.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Each type that implements `Num` has its own implementation of `fromInteger`. You might want to read about *type classes* to understand what happens here.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

This is a solution, perhaps not the best one but it works:

```
class YesNo a where
     yesno  ::  a -> Bool


instance YesNo Int where
     yesno 0    =   False
     yesno _    =   True


instance YesNo Integer where
     yesno 0    =   False
     yesno _    =   True
```