# Ambiguous type variable a0' arising from the literal 1' on list

Tags: haskell

```
elementAt :: (Show a, Num b, Eq b) => [a] -> b -> a
elementAt [] _ = error "No elementAt for empty lists!"
elementAt [x] 0 = x
elementAt (_:xs) n = elementAt xs (n-1)


main :: IO ()
main = print $ elementAt [1,2,3]
```

I get

```
   * Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from the literal `1'
      prevents the constraint `(Num a0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Num Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
        instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
        instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
        ...plus two others
        ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    * In the expression: 1
      In the first argument of `elementAt', namely `[1, 2, 3]'
      In the second argument of `($)', namely `elementAt [1, 2, 3]'
  |
6 | main = print $ elementAt [1,2,3]
  |                           ^
```

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/8546479/10116440 which tells me that I should choose a type for the number. So I think here I should choose a type for the list. How can I do that? And couldn't Haskell be smart enough to know that this list has only integers? If I really wanted Double I'd annotate it to be `[Double]`

Comment: `[1,2.2,3]` is valid. `[1,2.2]` is valid. `[1]` is valid. see? is `1` an integer in all three? in none?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a type annotation with a double colon:

```
main = print $ elementAt ([1,2,3] :: [Int])
```

Or like this:

```
main = print $ elementAt [(1 :: Int),2,3]
```

> couldn't Haskell be smart enough to know that this list has only integers?

The meaning of the program could change depending on the type. Plus, there are several types of integers - e.g. `Int` and `Integer`. Plus, numeric literals can be of any type that has a `Num` instance, they don't need to be actual numbers.

---

Finally, FYI you're missing a second parameter to `elementAt`.